# How do I Data-Bind dual DateTimePicker to a single DateTime object

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a simple form, with two DateTimePicker-controls: One for date, and one for time. The thing is these two controls are supposed to represent a single point in time. Hence I would like to "Bind" them to a single DateTime property on my form (for simplicity). I did the following:

```
// Start is a DateTime property on the form
_StartDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "Start"); 
_StartTime.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "Start");
```

But hooking into "ValueChanged" event, yields mixed results... Sometimes I get exactly what I want, sometimes the updates of the property are "sluggish". I figured this way of splitting into two DateTimePicker's was fairly common. So how to do it?

**Update:** There is possibly multiple questions in there:

1. How do I bind a DateTimePicker (Format: Date) to a DateTime Property on a form?
2. Then, how do I bind yet another DateTimePicker (Format: Time) to the same property?
3. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2008 (.NET 3.5), and I seemingly get ValueChanged events from the DateTimePickers **before** the value is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you may be finding yourself writing a custom control that includes both, which you can data bind to. That's how we solved the same problem.

Comment: Really? 
I thought this was so common, that it was possible out-of-the-box. Go figure...

Comment: I agree. It really ought to be available out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

I find myself having this problem on occasion and I use a somewhat ugly technique. Instead of binding directly to the property I create two additional properties on the model.

```
//The data I want to bind to
public DateTime Something { get; set; }
//Two new properties
public DateTime SomethingDate { /*...*/ }
public DateTime SomethingTime { /*...*/ }
```

The `get` sections of each should merely return `Something`. The `set` sections is where you implement a tiny bit of logic to ensure `Something` is always reflected accurately.

```
public DateTime SomethingDate
{
    get
    {
        return this.Something;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Something = value.Date.Add(this.Something.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
public DateTime SomethingTime
{
    get
    {
        return this.Something;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Something = this.Something.Date.Add(value.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

Now your `Something` property will always properly reflect the corresponding date and times of the two controls while only updating the value with the piece of information from each that we care about.

Comment: I'll try this to see if that solves my current problem. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain exactly how you do the binding then? I tried writing the "Something" to the Console on the ValueChangedEvent of the DataPicker bound to "SomethingDate". But when I pick a new date, the Console keeps writing the same date over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly bind DateTime struct member with a Binding Class,
for do it you have to wrap a DateTime struct and Implement the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface like this one:

```
public class DateTimeWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _dateTime;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
    }

    public DateTime Value
    {
        get { return _dateTime; }
        set
        {
            _dateTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and after that you can use a Bindig object like this:

```
var binding = new Binding("Value", _time, "Value", true);
binding.ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I used the solution found here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/display-the-date-and-time-in-separate-controls-HA010082330.aspx

That works fine and is a no code solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I just read the article, and didn't find the answer I was looking for. The article simply deals with configuring e.g. a "DatePicker" to show date only. I already know how to do that. The problem is the "dual-binding" of two controls to a shared DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

I have a public `DateTime` property in my WinForm named EpDayOnly.
Then I bind the datetimepicker's date with the property by writing:

```
myDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "EpDayOnly", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

When I open the form I set the datetime property by writing for example

```
myNewForm.EpDayOnly=DateTime.Parse("5/5/2012");
```

and this is reflected to the datetimepicker control.

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question: Specifically I have 2 DateTimePicker controls (one for time and one for date), and basically would like these to share data.